# subsubsection labels always start at 1

Tags: formatting, chapters, labels

When I use \subsubsection, its label is like a subsection starting at 1.

My input:

```
\section{}
\subsection{}
\subsubsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsubsection{}
```

What I want:

1.

1.1

1.1.1

1.2

1.2.1

What I'm getting:

1.

1.1

1.1

1.2

1.1

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) We are flattered that you think we can read minds `:-)` but, unfortunately, most of us can't and we actually need to look at some code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: the input you show does not make the output that you show unless you have extra code redefining it, if you are asking us to guess what you have done wrong I would guess that you have  `\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}` so it is not prefixed by the section number, but don't make us guess, show an example that produces the output that you show.

Comment: What is `\thesecnumdepth` (possibly `\arabic{secnumdepth}`)?  If it is too low (<2?) then the subsection counter is never incremented and `\label` will use the results from `\refstepcounter{section}` instead.